# How to Change Angular Dart Tour of Heroes to Firebase Backend

Tags: firebase, angular-dart, webapp2

I am using the Angular Dart Tour of Heroes sample project ([Here](https://webdev.dartlang.org/examples/toh-6/#dashboard)) for a project I'm working on to learn the platform. What is required to change to Firebase Backend instead of feeding data from the in_memory_data_service.dart ?

I think that the HeroService needs to be converted to pull from FireBase, but can't quite figure it out. Spent several days working through it with no success.

Didn't add the code because it's so much, but I can if it helps.

Comment: If the code is too much to post here, the answer is also going to be too long to post. As you've posted it now, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. If you're stuck on a specific step, post the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this another way. The Tour of Heroes HeroService was dependent on the mockData.

I was able to simple initialize the app and pull the data from FireBase in the appComponent.